# How to use correctly a CakePHP plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I've developed a bug tracker using CakePHP 2.4.4. I made this as a standalone cakephp app but now I wanna transfer it to a plugin, in order to reuse it in other projects.
As I already read at the docs  (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html), I have followed the instructions from there and created the correct folder and files structure. This is what i've done so far: https://github.com/lubbleup/BugCake/tree/plugin

But now,when i try to use the plugin in a separate cakephp installation, I cannot understand how to make of the plugin and, for example, use it's controllers and functionality etc.

can anyone help me out here?

ps:this is my first time trying to create a cakephp plugin

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which part you do not understand? Please be more specific about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the plugins your parent app in `APP/Config/bootstrap.php`

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

You do not need `AppModel` or `AppController` in your plugin. Your plugin has an own AppController/-Model named `PluginNameAppController`/`PluginNameAppModel`.

You can call your plugin at `http://host/plugin_name/controller/action/[...]`. In your case `http://host/bug_cake/issues/view/1` for instance.

But you can also use custom routes in your plugin with plenty of options.

Hope that answers your question—if not, comment.